# Custom error pages for PROD environment only?

Tags: symfony

How can I setup custom error pages for PROD environment only? I want to show custom ones for production but ordinary ones with exceptions for dev environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you need is int the Cookbook (DEV exception page is still the same, it only affects PROD environment) : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and solution was pretty easy. You have to modify parameter `twig.exception_listener.contoller` to redirect rendering of error page to your own controller, which may extend original Twig exception controller.

Example (`YourBundle/Resources/config/services.xml`):

```
<parameter key="twig.exception_listener.controller">YourBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction</parameter>
```

Then you have to create your own ExceptionController with method `showAction`, check for environment and do what you want to do or pass request to `parent::showAction()`.

```
namespace YourBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController as BaseExceptionController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ExceptionController extends BaseExceptionController {

    public function showAction(FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null, $format = 'html') {
        $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');

        if ($kernel->getEnvironment() == 'prod') {
            $request = $this->container->get('request');
            $request->setRequestFormat($format);

            $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
            $code = $exception->getStatusCode();

            $template = new TemplateReference('YourBundle', 'Exception', 'errorpage', $format, 'twig');
            if ($templating->exists($template)) {
                    $response = $templating->renderResponse($template, array(
                        'status_code' => $code,
                        'message_code' => 'error_' . $code,
                        'status_text' => Response::$statusTexts[$code],
                        'requested_url' => $request->getUri(),
                ));

                $response->setStatusCode($code);
                $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());

                return $response;
            }
        }

        return parent::showAction($exception, $logger, $format);
    }
}
```

Beware of errors in errorpage.html.twig, because exceptions in twig processing are not handled as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override the exception controller :

You can first copy the entire folder (or specific layout file) at

```
\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources\views\
```

to

```
\app\Resources\TwigBundle\views
```

Then customise the view in each layout file to match your design.

Then in the layout file, customise the message for each environment as follow

```
{% if app.environment == 'prod' %}
// message for prod
{% else %}
// message for dev
{% endif %}
```